# Why is inline style being overridden

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to put a border around a div.

```
<div style="border-color: yellow; border-style: dotted; border: 5px;">
<p>
    This is a test.
</p>
</div>
```

Yet when I run this, this is what the browser shows as the actual style being applied:

```
<div style="border: 5px currentColor;">...</div>
```

The result is that no border is shown at all.

This makes no sense to me why the border styles are being overridden.  I can only imagine that Bootstrap has set an !important override somewhere, but I have been unable to trace this.

Comment: You can use the web inspector in your browser (developer tools in Chrome, Firebug in Firefox) to trace inherited styles. This way, in a first step, you can eliminate any `!importance` that interferes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order in which you are applying inline styling. You can add all the 3 styling in the `border` style itself like `border:5px dotted yellow;`. Well if you still want to go with the way you did, just change the order. First add the `border` style and then specify the other styles like this.

```
<div style="border: 5px; border-color: yellow; border-style: dotted;">
<p>
    This is a test.
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I get it now.  "Border: 5px" by itself is shorthand for "Border: 5px none currentColor" So since it was last in the style, it was overriding the specified border-color and border-style.  What I really meant to write was 'border-width' not 'border'.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome Inpsector:

- click the element you wish to inspect
- On the right, select the **Computed** tab

There you can see the applied styles, and their sources, so it would give you an idea why it is overridden.

- you can always use `!important` yourself as well.

[image]